# Check if a variable is equal to any of several values

Tags: java

I'm trying to check if an integer is equal to any of several values and don't want to do this:

```
int d = 0;
if(d == 3 || d == 8 || d == 1) {
    System.out.println("d is one of the special numbers!");
}
```

How can I accomplish this when it comes to hundreds or thousands of values?

Comment: Must it be an exact match? Will you accept false positives? Have you looked at the `Set` data structure?

Comment: @MichaelT It doesn't have to be. I want to perform an action if it is one of those values.

Comment: You can use a collection to store all your special values and then check against. As @MichaelT has suggested, set sounds like an optimal choice. And if there is some other predefined property linked with a number, go with a map.

Comment: Are you hardcoding the data?

Answer (score 18):

There are two diverging approaches to this based on the key question of "are false positives acceptable?"  This means "If I want to test if 42 is one of your special numbers, and it isn't in your special number set, is it ok to say 'yes'?"

If it is, you fall into the realm of the [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).  This has the advantage that it is small, and fast, and will probably get it right.  It will come back with an answer of "possibly in the set" or "definitely not in the set."  Early spell checkers used this to compress huge dictionaries down to a few kilobytes (can't fit too much on a 140k floppy).

But, as this pointed out, again, it may say 'yes' when the answer is 'no'.

A more conventional approach is to use a `Set`.  In Java, this is found in the [java.util.Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface and there are quite a few of implementing classes.  Most commonly used, the HashSet and TreeSet.

The set contains, well, a set of values.  It has a method to add them (and remove them) and test to see if the set contains a given value (or values).  Its really a rather straight forward data structure.

```
Set<Integer> foo = new HashSet<Integer>();
foo.add(3);
foo.add(8);
foo.add(1);

...

if (foo.contains(d)) { ... }
```

Doesn't matter how big the Set is.  Be it three or three thousand (or more) values. It works just as well.

To this end, I would suggest reading more about the [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html).  There are a lot of classes there that have a number of uses. You will find yourself often using these classes - Lists, Sets, and Maps are the fundamentals of a large part of programming problems.  Understanding *which* List or Set or Map to use can be quite important in the behavior (do you want the results back when iterating in insert order? sorted order? don't care?).

Comment: So I'd need numerous if statements for foo?

Comment: @jay No matter how many entires foo contains, the test `if (foo.contains(d))` will see if d is in there or not. Be there three or three thousand entries. I'd suggest that you grab that code and play with it in your example to see how it works. You'll still have to *add* the values to the set somehow, but you can test against all of them in one go with the set.

Comment: Then, there is `BitSet` which is not part of the Collections framework but provides a way of keeping positive `int`s and telling whether one is contained or not. Depending on the actual values it might be much more efficient than `HashSet<Integer>` and `TreeSet<Integer>`. But the logic remains the same.

Comment: `BitSet` is the correct answer, kudos to @Holger.